# Google Map full-screen control is not visible on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-chrome

I have implement a web page that include a google map component. In the map all other map controls(zoom, satellite, and etc.) are properly visible except the full screen control. The issue recreates only on google chrome. If I load the same page with Microsoft Edge, all the controls (including full screen control) are visible.

I looked into html code using inspect element developer tool. When I inspect on google chrome and edge the results were different. Please see following html code.

HTML on google chrome

```
<button draggable="false" title="Toggle fullscreen view" aria-label="Toggle fullscreen view" type="button" style="background: none rgb(255, 255, 255); display: none; border: 0px; margin: 10px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; user-select: none; top: 30px; right: 0px;">
</button>
```

HTML on Microsoft Edge

```
<button title="Toggle fullscreen view" class="gm-control-active gm-fullscreen-control" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); margin: 10px; padding: 0px; border-radius: 2px; border: 0px; border-image: none; top: 30px; width: 40px; height: 40px; right: 0px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); -ms-user-select: none;" draggable="false" aria-label="Toggle fullscreen view" type="button">
    <img style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2218%22%20height%3D%2218%22%20viewBox%3D%220%20018%2018%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23666%22%20d%3D%22M0%2C0v2v4h2V2h4V0H2H0z%20M16%2C0h-4v2h4v4h2V2V0H16z%20M16%2C16h-4v2h4h2v-2v-4h-2V16z%20M2%2C12H0v4v2h2h4v-2H2V12z%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0A">
    <img style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2218%22%20height%3D%2218%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2018%2018%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23333%22%20d%3D%22M0%2C0v2v4h2V2h4V0H2H0z%20M16%2C0h-4v2h4v4h2V2V0H16z%20M16%2C16h-4v2h4h2v-2v-4h-2V16z%20M2%2C12H0v4v2h2h4v-2H2V12z%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0A">
    <img style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2218%22%20height%3D%2218%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2018%2018%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23111%22%20d%3D%22M0%2C0v2v4h2V2h4V0H2H0z%20M16%2C0h-4v2h4v4h2V2V0H16z%20M16%2C16h-4v2h4h2v-2v-4h-2V16z%20M2%2C12H0v4v2h2h4v-2H2V12z%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0A">
</button>
```

Has anyone come up with such a situation and found any solution for that.

Comment: Please mention any reason if you're going to down vote the question. Or please edit the question if its format is incorrect.

Comment: Can you please post the code used to load your Google map? Or better can you provide a jsfiddle so that we can reproduce this from our side?

Comment: I have tried that method also. I implemented a separate simple html code with same JS to load map. It works fine. The issue recreates only on salesforce sandbox. It works fine on salesforce production as well.

Comment: I see, then it looks like salesforce's own css could be conflicting here, or there is an issue with its dependencies maybe. Anyway, it will be pretty hard to help you if I can't reproduce this at all so would you be able to provide as much code and info as possible?

Comment: Thank you for your consideration. I will try to recreate it and try to post more information. I cannot post existing code as the code belongs to the company.

Comment: Sure thing, please keep me posted. :)